# Laravel Login Attempt Prerequisites

Tags: php, laravel, session

My website requires a users account to be activated by an email link that is sent out to them before they can actually log in however the guard() attempt() method seems to sign the user in as long as there is a match. How would I just check without logging in so I can validate the user > verify their account is active > start a user session? The current code is as follows

```
if ($this->guard()->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember'))) {
       // Return response if user match found
       return $this->checkAccountActive($credentials);
}
```

Comment: Tell me your email link

Answer (score 0):

Are you using AuthController?

In case you do you can adjust the getCredentials() method to meet your business requirements, for example if you need the email confirmed and the status active you could do something like the following:

```
protected function getCredentials($request)
{
    return array_merge($request->only(['email', 'password']), ['active' => 1]);
}
```

Comment: I am using the AuthenticatesUsers triat that comes with Laravel 5.3. I am logging in using a username, password and a boolean called "active". Will the above method still work?

Comment: Find AuthController.php in app/Http/Controllers/Auth and  replace the getCredentials() method with the above.

Comment: Your method didn't work but I used "$request->merge(array('active' => '1'));" instead